# "TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, user-defined-functions

```
# Print out a nice report
print("\nData Quality Report")
print("Total records: {}".format(len(cust_dmgc.index)))
data_quality_report
```

output:
[image]

I want the above output from User defined function. I tried to to make one... like this:

```
def DataQuality_Report(df):
    # columns
    globals() [columns] = pd.DataFrame(list(df.columns))

    #Data Types
    globals() [data_types] = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes, columns=['DataType'])

    #Missing Values
    globals() [missing_data_counts] = pd.DataFrame(df.isnull().sum(), columns= ['Missing Values'])

    #Missing Percentage
    globals() [missing_data_pct] = pd.DataFrame(((df.isnull().sum() / df.shape[0]) * 100).round(2) , columns= ['Missing Values %'])

    #Present Counts
    globals() [present_data_counts] = pd.DataFrame(df.count(), columns= ['Present Values'])

    #No. of Unique Values
    globals() [unique_value_counts] = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Unique Values'])

    for v in list(df.columns.values):
        unique_value_counts.loc[v] = [df[v].nunique()]
    
    #Minimum Values for numeric data
    globals() [minimum_values] = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Minimum Value'])

    for v in list(df.columns.values):
        if df[v].dtype != 'O':
             minimum_values.loc[v] = [df[v].min()]
        else:
             minimum_values.loc[v] = "-"
        
    #Maximum Values for numeric data
    globals() [maximum_values] = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['Maximum Value'])

    for v in list(df.columns.values):
        if df[v].dtype != 'O':
            maximum_values.loc[v] = [df[v].max()]
        else:
            maximum_values.loc[v] = "-"
    # Merge all the dataframes together by the index
    globals() [data_quality_report] = data_types.join(present_data_counts).join(missing_data_counts)\ .join(missing_data_pct).join(unique_value_counts).join(minimum_values).join(maximum_values)

    #Output
    print("\nData Quality Report")
    print("Total records: {}".format(len(df.index)))
    data_quality_report
```

And this is giving me an error 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

I used globals() because I want those individual data frames to use outside that function.

[image]

Please guide me on how to fix this? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Post code not the images of code

Comment: Why are you messing with `globals()` to begin with? That's a highly questionable design choice

Comment: I have edited my question with the code replaced the image - @bigbounty. Please check and help me.

Comment: I want to declare them globally so that I can use them anywhere in analysis. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Removing globals() worked for returning data_quality_report dataframe from the user-defined function, as mentioned above. But, my intension was to use the other individual DataFrames out  of the function, which is not the case with this way.

Comment: @veerendrabhadrachalam, I'm getting a similar error attempting to do a similar thing in a different way, but have you tried returning a dict or df packed with all those dfs you want to use outside the function instead of using globals()?